# General advice? GUI with Buffered Reader/Writer for ACH in JAVA

Tags: java, user-interface, batch-processing

I posted here a few weeks ago regarding a project I have for work. The project began as creating a simple little program that would take an incoming ACH file and read each line. The program would also ask a user for a "reason code" and "bank" which would affect the next step. The program would then reformat all the data in a certain way and save it to an external file. For those that don't know, an ACH is simply a text based file that is in a very concrete format. (Every character and space has a meaning.)

I have completed that task using a few GUI items (Jcombobox, JFileChooser, etc), string array lists, buffered reader/writer, and lots of if/else statements.

The task has now been expanded to a much more complicated and I don't know exactly how to begin, so I thought I would seek the communities advice.

When an ACH file comes in it will be in a format that looks something like this:

```
101 100000000000000000000000000000
522 00000202020382737327372732737237
6272288381237237123712837912738792178
6272392390123018230912830918203810
627232183712636283761231726382168
822233473498327497384798234724273487398
522 83398402830943240924332849832094
62723921380921380921382183092183
6273949384028309432083094820938409832
82283409384083209482094392830404829304
900000000000000000000000000000000
9999999999999999999999999999999999999
9999999999999999999999999999999999999
```

(I will refer to each line by " " number, for example "1 number" are the lines that begin with 1)

The end result is that the lines of data are maniuplated and put into "batches". The output file begins with the "1 number"
and then contains a batch with the format of

```
5
6
8
5
6
8
5
6
8
```

We continue using the same "5 number" until all sixes that were below it in the original file have been written, then we go to the next "5" and work with the "6" below it.

So, my project now is to create a full GUI. After the user inputs the file the GUI will have some type of drop down box or similar list of all the "6" numbers. For each number there should be another drop down box to choose the reason code (there are 7 reason codes).

Basically the ultimate objective is:

1. Display all the "6" numbers and give the user the ability to choose a reason code for each.
2. Allow the user to only select a certain amount of the "6" numbers if they wish.

   Is it possible for me to do this using Buffered Reader/ Writer? I currently save the values into Array Lists using the following code:

   ```
               while((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) !=null)//<---------This loop will continue while there are still lines to be read. 
               {
                   if (sCurrentLine.startsWith("5")){//<------------------If the line starts with "5"..
                       listFive.add(sCurrentLine);//<-------------------------Add the line to the array list "listFive".
                       countFive++;//<---------------------------------------------Increase the counter "countFive" by one. 
                   }else if (sCurrentLine.startsWith("6") && countFive==1){//<---------If the line starts with "6" and countFive is at a value of 1..
                       listSix.add(sCurrentLine);//<---------------------------------------Add the line to the array list "listSix".
                   }else if (sCurrentLine.startsWith("6") && countFive==2){//<-----------------If the line starts with "6" and countFive is at a value of 2..
                       listSixBatchTwo.add(sCurrentLine);//<--------------------------------------Add the line to the array list "listSixBatchTwo".
                   }else if (sCurrentLine.startsWith("6") && countFive==3){//<-----------------------If the line starts with "6" and countFive is at a value of 3..
                       listSixBatchThree.add(sCurrentLine);//<------------------------------------------Add the line to array list "listSixBatchThree".
                   }else if (sCurrentLine.startsWith("6") && countFive==4){//<------------------------------If the line starts with "6" and countFive is at a value of 4..
                       listSixBatchFour.add(sCurrentLine); //<--------------------------------------------------Add the line to array list "listSixBatchFour".
                   }else if (sCurrentLine.startsWith("8")){//<-----------------------------------------------------If the line starts with "8"..
                       listEight.add(sCurrentLine);//<----------------------------------------------------------------Add the line to array list "listEight".
                   }else if (sCurrentLine.startsWith("1")){//<-----------------------------------------------------------If the line starts with "1"..
                       one = sCurrentLine;//<-------------------------------------------------------------------------------Save the line to String "one". 
                   }else if (sCurrentLine.startsWith("9") && count9 == 1){//<---------------------------------------------------If the line starts with "9" and count9 is at a value of 1..
                       nine = sCurrentLine;//<-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Save the line to String "nine".
                       count9 = 0;//<--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Set count9 to a value of 0. 
                   }else if (sCurrentLine.startsWith("999") && count9 == 0){//<-----------------------------------------------------------If the line starts with "999" and count9 is at a value of 0..
                       listNine.add(sCurrentLine);//<---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Add the line to array list "listNine".
                   }else{
                   }
               }
   ```

If anyone can point me where I can get started I would be very grateful. If you need more information please let me know.

Update:

Here is an example of my JOptionPane with decision making.

```
String[] choices = {"Wells Fargo", "Bank of America", "CitiBank", "Wells Fargo Legacy", "JPMC"};
            String input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Bank Selection", "Please choose a bank: ", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,   choices, choices[0]);
            if (input.equals("Wells Fargo"))
            {
                bank = "WELLS FARGO";

            }else if (input.equals("Bank of America")){
                bank = "BANK OF AMERICA";

            }else if (input.equals("CitiBank")){
                bank = "CITI BANK";

            }else if (input.equals("Wells Fargo Legacy")){
                bank = "WELLS FARGO LEGACY";

            }else if (input.equals("JPMC")){
                bank = "JPMC";


            }
            }else{

            }
```

Let's assume I wanted to use the Buffered Writer to save all of the "6" numbers into a String array, then put them into a drop down box in the GUI. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: To answer one question, yes, all your reading in of the text file can be solved with a BufferedReader (if it is truly a text file), but as for your `"can point me where I can get started..."` question, that's a bit vague and overly general, and about all I can say is that as with most large projects, one key to a solution is to try to break down the steps into smaller constituent steps, and then try to solve each single step, one at a time, often in isolation.

Comment: I would like to help you, but after reading your post three time, what do you search exactly : - help for your GUI, and how present your datas ? - You have somme interrogations on your code ? - else other ? Please clarify your need please. Regards FTE

Comment: Sorry, I guess I am so deep into it that I wasn't exactly sure where to start. As you have stated, it is best to break a project up into portions, so that is what I will do.

I guess the first question I have is: Can you use the input from Buffered Writer in a GUI.. Say a JOptionPane for example. If yes, then how could I go about doing that? 

In all the examples I have seen and tutorials about JOptionPane everything is done BEFORE the main method. What if I need if statements included in my JOptionPane input? How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I believe I just had an idea of how I need to proceed first. Can someone please verify?

1. Create static variables representing the lines that will be read. (Such as a static ArrayList<String>.
2. Create the actual GUI, outside the main Method.
3. Create the Buffered Reader which will write to the variables mentioned in #1, inside the main method. 
4. Call the GUI, inside the main method but after the Buffered Reader completes it's functions. 

Will this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you use the input from Buffered Writer in a GUI..

Well, a BufferedWriter is not used to get input but rather to output information, but assuming that you meant a BufferedReader, then the answer is yes, definitely. Understand that a GUI and getting data with a BufferedReader are orthogonal concepts -- they both can work just fine independently of the other. The main issues involving reading in data with a Bufferedhaving a GUI

> Say a JOptionPane for example.

I'm not sure what you mean here or how this relates.

> If yes, then how could I go about doing that? In all the examples I have seen and tutorials about JOptionPane everything is done BEFORE the main method. What if I need if statements included in my JOptionPane input? How can I accomplish this?

I'm not sure what you mean by "everything is done before the main method", but it sounds like you may be getting ahead of yourself. Before worrying about nuts and bolts and specific location of code, think about what classes/objects your program will have, and how they'll interact -- i.e., what methods they will have.

> I believe I just had an idea of how I need to proceed first. Can someone please verify? 1. Create static variables representing the lines that will be read. (Such as a static ArrayList.

No, don't think about static anything off the bat, since once you do that, you leave the OOP realm and go into procedural programming. The main data should be held in instance variables within a class or two.

> 2. Create the actual GUI, outside the main Method.

I'm not sure what you mean "outside the main method", but the GUI will consist of multiple classes, probably one main one, and an instance of the main class is not infrequently created in the main method, or in a method called by the main method, but queued onto the Swing event thread.

> 3. Create the Buffered Reader which will write to the variables mentioned in #1, inside the main method.

Again, I wouldn't do this. The main method should be short, very short, and its reason for existence is only to start your key objects and set them running, and that's it. Nothing critical (other than just what I stated) should be done in them. You're thinking small toy programs, and that's not what you're writing.  The reader should be an instance variable inside of its own class. It might be started indirectly by the GUI via a control class which is a class that responds to GUI events. If you need the data prior to creation of the GUI, then you will have your main method create the class that reads in the data, ask it to get the data, and then create your GUI class, passing the data into it.